# Add changes in a single file to multiple changelists

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Is it possible to somehow add one file to multiple changes when I made changes that belong to seperate commits (semantically speaking)?

It is possible to select certain lines in the GitHub for Mac app, but I need this feature for an SVN project.

Comment: I want it too. Launching SourceTree now just for that funciton.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible. If you add file to one list, then switch to another list and then you edit same file you will get warrning.